# Skeleton loader blinks when the data loads too fast

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, fetch-api, placeholder

I'm using Vue 3 and I try to implement a skeleton loader for a placeholder when the data is loading and I can see it works if I turn on throttling in the Network tab of the browser. However, when the data loads too quick, I can also see how the skeleton loader blinks.

Here I tried using a `setTimeout` and inside I put the `isLoaded` ref which value is set to true when the image is fully loaded. But what the delay does is it prolongs time, and I need to skeleton loader be not visible when the data loads fast. I want it only be visible, when the data loads slowly.

```
onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
    img.onload = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            isLoaded.value = true;
        }, 300);
    };
    img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
});
```

Update:
This is how I use skeleton loader in the `<template>`:

```
<ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending === false || !isLoaded" />
<template v-else>
    <img
        class="card__image"
        :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
        :alt="recipe.alt"
        width="15.625rem"
        loading="lazy" />
    <div class="card__content">
        <h2 class="card__title">{{ recipe.title }}</h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

Please, give a solution.

Comment: What version of vue? 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Vue 3

Comment: Regardless of what you do there will be some sort of flash depending on how long the image takes to load ... if you delay the appearance of the skeleton by, for example, 300ms, if the image loads under that time, good, if it loads well over that time, good, if it loads in say 310ms ... bad .... substitute any number for 300, and there will always be a particular time taken for the image to load that will create the effect you are trying to fix - just make your skeleton more subtle

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you exactly mean by making the skeleton 'more subtle'?

Comment: less obvious, so the inevitable flash (by that, see previous comment) isn't as obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave the skeleton logic alone, just fade it in after some time, avoiding the jump in content if you delay displaying the skeleton (as discussed in @Phil's answer)

The example below, there's no skeleton visible for 1000ms, then the skeleton will fade in for 1000ms - the times are probably longer than you want, I just wrote it this way to see it actually working - so, just adjust the `animation-duration` (and `animation-timing-function` if you want) as appropriate to your needs

```
<style scoped>
@keyframes skeletonAnimate {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
.skeleton {
    opacity:0;
    animation-name: skeletonAnimate;
    animation-duration: 2000ms;
    animation-direction: forward;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
</style>
```

Not sure how your skeleton is done, but here's a non-vue demo in action

```css
@keyframes skeletonAnimate {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.skeleton-content {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: skeletonAnimate;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-direction: forward;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes bgAnimate {
  0% {
    background-position: 50% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -150% 0;
  }
}

.skeleton {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right, hsla(210, 2%, 54%, 20%) 0%, hsla(210, 4%, 89%, 20%) 10%, hsla(210, 2%, 54%, 20%) 40%, hsla(210, 2%, 54%, 20%) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);
  animation: bgAnimate 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton-content">
<div class="skeleton"></div>
</div>
Other content
```

Comment: Nice one. Could also make use of Vue's [transitions](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition) to avoid some boilerplate and the keyframes

Comment: Indeed @Phil I hadn't considered that

Comment: @Phil I was just thinking about transitions, but I thought it's a vue-router feature. So I basically can apply it to any component?

Comment: @JaromandaX what if I want to display `<ItemSkeletonLoader/>` component instead of the content, using `v-if` when the data is loading? In this case, I don't have any overlay, and if I add the `class="skeleton-overlay"` with opacity: 0 to the `<ItemSkeletonLoader/>`, it won't disappear and the blank space is left instead of the content.

Comment: @Michael - Sorry, I can't follow - perhaps example of actual code

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean you have two divs in your example `<div class="skeleton-content">
<div class="skeleton"></div>`, but what if I have a component `<ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending === true || !isLoaded" />`? and `v-else` on the content. If I add the class="skeleton-overlay" with opacity: 0 to the <ItemSkeletonLoader/>, it won't disappear and the blank space is left instead of the content.

Comment: My example isn't vuejs at all for a start, and since I have no way of knowing anything about your skeleton component I have no way of knowing how you implement this suggestion into your component

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I didn't know. You just used `<style scoped>`, which is a Vuejs feature, so I thought the answer is related to Vue as well. I have a basic skeleton loader inside `<ItemCardSkeleton />` with one div and `@keyframes skeleton-loading {
    0% {
        background-color: hsl(200, 20%, 70%);
    }
    100% {
        background-color: hsl(200, 20%, 95%);
    }
}`

Comment: `You just used <style scoped>` well, yes, that was from one of my actual vue apps, so I know how my skeleton is implemented, and I just copy/pasted the style block :p

Comment: @Michael - my skeleton is a little more convoluted. Firstly, I have an `AnimatedPlaceholder` - which basically is a single div with a similar animation to the snippet in the answer. Then I have a series of skeletons for different purposes. One being `UserCardSkeleton` which uses 4 x AnimatedPlaceholder to look a bit like my `UserCard` (one round avatar, one heading, two lines of text) - it's the `UserCardSkeleton` in this case that gets faded in over 2 seconds - let me see if I can mock something up on codesandbox

Comment: @JaromandaX I just wanted to conditionally render a skeleton loader component, instead of using an overlay and animating opacity on this overlay. Because if I leave the skeleton present in the dom it's an unnecessarily space for a placeholder, and it can be optimized.

Comment: well ... that's what `v-if`/`v-else` is for ... as I said, you have not shown any useful code regarding how you do the skeleton - here's a [mock up](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/delicate-bush-2l8lk9) based on actual code

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the question and added the code regarding the skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to skeleton loader be not visible when the data loads fast. I want it only be visible, when the data loads slowly.

Sounds like you need a timeout on displaying the skeleton instead. Cancel it when the data is loaded.

For example, display the skeleton after a suitable minimum delay, eg 100ms. If the data loads first, don't display it at all.

```js
const showPlaceholder = ref(false);

// ...

onMounted(async () => {
  // wait 100ms to show the placeholder
  const placeholderTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    showPlaceholder.value = true;
  }, 100);

  const img = new Image(); // the constructor only accepts dimensions, not src
  img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
  await img.decode(); // much easier to use than onload
  clearTimeout(placeholderTimer);
  showPlaceholder.value = false;
  isLoaded.value = true;
});
```

Then use the `showPlaceholder` ref value to conditionally render the skeleton.

Comment: what if the data loads after 210ms :p same issue for different load times

Comment: @JaromandaX OP can figure out a suitable minimum wait time

Comment: @JaromandaX personally, I'd go with the approach they currently have which is to always show the skeleton for a minimum time but that's apparently not what they want ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: `OP can figure out a suitable minimum wait time` and then any time + short interval will be the same problem - how to chase your tail in code :p

Comment: `always show the skeleton for a minimum time` I agree, or make the skeleton subtle :p

Comment: @JaromandaX agreed. I suspect though that cached image data is loading instantly

Comment: is using timeout in this case is what's usually done in real projects?

Comment: @Michael "real" projects understand that any timeout will not fix this issue, just "move" it to a different time - having said that, for reasons in the comments, I can see why a 200ms delay may be beneficial (I'd probably go 100, but that's me)

Comment: the remaining issue is, if the skeleton isn't present for 100/200ms whatever, then there will be a jump in the page when the skeleton or image appear - I'd leave the skeleton logic alone, and have it fade in over time ... the first 100ms or whatever opacity from 0 to 0 (i.e. no fade at first) then the next 100ms opacity transitions to 100%

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd upvote that as an answer

Comment: @Phil I think I can't mark a comment as an answer. If Jaromanda X could give a whole answer I could be able to click on 'Accept this answer'.